# google play games: get the total amount of requested players from an invitation id

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am trying to code a multiplayer game in Android using Google Play Games. Everything is working for automatches, but I can't figure out how to decide when to start on an invite game.

My network manager has a shouldStartGame() function like this:

```
boolean shouldStartGame(Room room) 
{
    int connectedPlayers = 0;
    for (Participant p : room.getParticipants()) {
        if (p.isConnectedToRoom()) ++connectedPlayers;
    }
    return connectedPlayers >= this.totalRequestedPlayers;
}
```

When the game is a automatch game, this is fine - totalRequestedPlayers gets populated in onActivityResult, when the Select Players dialog returns

```
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
if (request == NetworkManager.RC_SELECT_PLAYERS)
{
final ArrayList<String> invitees = data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);

// get auto-match criteria
Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
int minAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
int maxAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);

if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) 
{
    autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
            minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
} 
else 
{
    autoMatchCriteria = null;
}

this.oNetwork.setTotalRequestedPlayers(invitees.size() + minAutoMatchPlayers);
RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(getApiClient(), roomConfig);

// prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

However, when starting an match in response to an invitation from another player, I can't find any way of interrogating the room or the configBuilder to find out how many players are required...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedState)
{   
String invitationID=this.getIntent().getExtras().getString(NetworkManager.EXTRA_ROOM_ID);
if(invitationID.equals(""))
{
    //invite some people
    this.oNetwork.beginInviteFriends(); 
}
else
{
//we have been invited to a room
    RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder =
            this.oNetwork.makeStandardRoomConfigForGameType(this);
    roomConfigBuilder.setInvitationIdToAccept(invitationID);

    RoomConfig c = roomConfigBuilder.build();

    this.oNetwork.setTotalRequestedPlayers(999);  // <-  need to figure out how to get this info
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.join(getApiClient(), c);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
}
```

I need to find out the total number of 'named' players from the original invitation, plus the amount of automatch requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function

```
@Override
public void onRoomConnected(int arg0, Room _room)
{

}
```

Tells you when all users, either invited, or auto matched, have connected to the room.